# php/mysql If status='Calibration' warn user

Tags: php, mysql

My goal with this code is to check if the status is set to "Calibration" and in that case the user will be warned by either echo or popup. I can't figure out how to get the code to work in that way and this is what I have right now. ->

EDIT: The problem right now is that the IF statement isn't working properly, the echo "This item is on Calibration"; is printed even if the status isn't calibration.

EDIT2: The problem is solved!

```
$DB = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "book1");
$result2 = mysqli_query($DB, "SELECT Status FROM booking WHERE itemID='$itemID'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
    echo $row['Status']. ",";
    $status = $row['Status'];
}
if ($status='Calibration'){
    echo "This item is on Calibration";
}
$upd = "UPDATE booking SET userID ='none/last user: $userID', Verification='$verification', status='Available' WHERE itemID ='$itemID'";
```

Comment: how is it not working? any errors?

Comment: @NoLiver92 The IF statement isn't working, it will always post the echo line

Comment: because you had wrote = instead of ==(comparison).

Comment: @LOKESH How couldn't I see that, well thanks :)

Comment: Please use prepared statements and bind your variables to make sure that you're not vulnerable towards SQL injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use comparision operator `==` instead of assignment `=`

```
if ($status == 'Calibration') {
    echo "This item is on Calibration";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In if statement you have `Status = 'Calibration'`. '=' is assignment not comaprison.

Change it to '==' and I guess your code should work then